# Почему не работает форма, добавленная PHP-скриптом

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Пытаюсь сделать такую форму: id/name, по submit запись добавляется в базу данных и воспроизводится на странице. Сама воспроизводимая запись имеет кнопку delete, по которой  должна удаляться из БД, и соответственно, со страницы. Действия производятся через AJAX запросы, и тут возникает проблема.
Имеется JS код: функция, выводящая все записи из БД, функция обработчик добавления, функция обработчик удаления.

```
function showAllRecords() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'showallrecords.php',
    success: function(html) {
      $('#records').html(html);
    }
  });
  return false;
}

showAllRecords();

$('#addrecord').submit(
  function() {
    var form = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'newobj.php',
      data: form
    });

    showAllRecords();
    return false;
  }
);

$('#deleteRecord').submit(
  function() {
    var form = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: form,
      url: 'deleteobj.php'

    });
    showAllRecords();
    return false;
  }
);
```

PHP скрипт добавления записи в БД:

```
<?php
require_once('login.php');

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
if ($connection->error)
    die($connection->error);

$id   = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$query  = "insert into test values('$id','$name')";
$result = $connection->query($query);
if (!$result)
    die($connection->error);

?>
```

PHP скрипт удаления записи:

```
<?php
require_once('login.php');

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
if ($connection->error)
    die($connection->error);

$id   = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$query  = "insert into test values('$id','$name')";
$result = $connection->query($query);
if (!$result)
    die($connection->error);

?>
```

PHP скрипт, выводящий все записи на страницу:

```
<?php
require_once('login.php');

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
if ($connection->error)
    die($connection->error);

$query  = "select *  from test";
$result = $connection->query($query);
if (!$result)
    die($connection->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

    $result->data_seek($i);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

    echo <<<_END
               <div class="aRecord">
                        id: $row[0]
                        <br>
                        name: $row[1]
                        <br>
                        <form id="deleteRecord">
                                <input type="hidden" name="deletingRecordID" value="$row[0]">
                                <input type="submit" value="delete">
                        </form>
                </div>
_END;
}
?>
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем. Добавление и воспроизведение записей происходит без проблем, все работает как должно, но функция-обработчик удаления, которая вызывается по кнопке, добавленной PHP-скриптом, не делает вообще ничего. Причем, если добавить аналогичную форму в HTML код самостоятельно и попробовать удалить какую-нибудь произвольную запись из БД, все работает. Почему не работает добавляемая скриптом форма?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `$('#deleteRecord').submit( function() {` использовать `$(document).on('submit', '#deleteRecord', function(){`  . Аналогично и с addrecord

Comment: Это помогло, в случае с простой тестовой функцией, которая выводит в абзац слово. Для моей задачи возникает вопрос насчет строки var form = $(this).serialize(); . Как в случае когда событие .on() применяется ко всему документу передать на сервер, какую запись следует удалить?

Comment: Судя по вашему коду у вас удаление и добавление имеет одинаковый запрос `$query  = "insert into test values('$id','$name')";`

Comment: @xaja это косяк добавления вопроса, в скрипте все нормально. В итоге, все заработало как надо, всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все заработало, изменил в коде запроса:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#deleteRecord', function() {
  var form = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: form,
    url: 'deleteobj.php'

  });
  showAllRecords();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что событие `submit()` не работает с динамично созданными элементами. В вашем случае нужно `on()`. Попробуйте так:

```
$('#deleteRecord').on('click',
  function() {
    var form = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: form,
      url: 'deleteobj.php'

    });
    showAllRecords();
    return false;
  }
);
```

Comment: Простая замена .submit(...) на .on('submit',...) или на  .on('click',...) не помогла, результат тот же. Частично помогла замена на $(document).on('submit',...) . Спасибо за ответ.